# De/encoding issue when storing foreign language text in dict in python

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I webscraped text in foreign language(Korean) with python, and store it inside dict.

The text alone prints into terminal just fine, but the dict prints as following:

{'title': u'\uc138\ubbf8\ub098 \ud6c4\uae30'}

How can I resolve this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

titleReponse = soupResponse.find('div','title').get_text()
print(titleReponse)
collected = {"title":titleReponse}
print(collected)
```

Comment: The best(?) solution, if possible, would be to change from Python 2 to Python 3 and you would not have this issue. If that is not possible, there are ways to achive what you want, but it requires a bit more information to find the correct solution in your case. What do you really want to achieve and why?

Comment: Why is it an issue that the *internal representation* of a string is not the way you want it?

Answer (score 1):

It is just the internal `__repr__` representation of a Unicode string under Python 2. As you already noticed, *printing* it shows the correct text:

```
>>> dict = {'title': u'\uc138\ubbf8\ub098 \ud6c4\uae30'}
>>> dict
{'title': u'\uc138\ubbf8\ub098 \ud6c4\uae30'}
>>> dict['title']
u'\uc138\ubbf8\ub098 \ud6c4\uae30'
print dict['title']
세미나 후기
```

You should not worry about the internal representation *at all*. Yes, for plain ASCII strings without control codes that is equal to what gets printed. But it is perfectly normal to have something like this:

```
>>> str = '123\n456'
>>> str
'123\n456'
>>> print str
123
456
```

where again the representation of the internal string differs from what gets output with `print`.

If you are going to work a lot with Unicode strings, best thing is to upgrade to Python 3. It has vastly superior support for Unicode. And a happy side effect is that in such cases, Unicode strings get displayed better (not "correct", but "better" – there is a difference ):

```
>>> dict = {'title': u'\uc138\ubbf8\ub098 \ud6c4\uae30'}
>>> dict
{'title': '세미나 후기'}
```